# Javascript ordered list and content

Tags: javascript

So my problem is about creating new element in ordered list with exact content. I have this homework and I am studying JS only for a couple of days. I have to make an ordered list and a button ADD ITEM. When I click the button it must create a new element in the ordered list with next number containig in it. So now when I click the button the prompt window appear and the text that I write goes in the next "li", but I can't figure how next "li" will display item 1, item 2, item 3 etc. And also I need to hide the first element cause "item 1: Text always shows up."

```js
function addItem() {
  var item = prompt("Please insert a text", "It will be added to the list");
  if (item != null) {
    var n = 0;
    var ol = document.getElementById("myList");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    ol.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML += "item " + n + ':' + item;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "&nbsp";
  }
}
```

```css
#nested {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#large {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
ol {
  list-style-type: arabic;
  list-style-position: inside;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="large">
  <div id="nested">
    <form method="get">
      <input type="button" id="resizeBut" name="resize" value="Collapse" onclick="change()" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="button" id="newItem" name="items" value="Add Item" onclick="addItem()" />
    </form>
    <ol reversed="reversed" class="right" id="myList">
      Unordered list
      <li>item 1:<span id="text">Text</span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're close, just move `var n=0` outside the function and increase it by one inside the function, also remove the `<li>` from the html, also remove `reversed="reversed"` from the `ol`, something like this  [codePen](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/XKxQmB?editors=1010) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Decalre var `n` outside of the `function`
- `Increment` it in every function call

```js
var n = 1;

function addItem() {
  var item = prompt("Please insert a text", "It will be added to the list");
  if (item != null) {
    ++n;
    var ol = document.getElementById("myList");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = "item " + n + ':' + item;
    ol.appendChild(li);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "&nbsp";
  }
}
```

```css
#nested {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#large {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
ol {
  list-style-type: arabic;
  list-style-position: inside;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="large">
  <div id="nested">
    <form method="get">
      <input type="button" id="resizeBut" name="resize" value="Collapse" onclick="change()" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="button" id="newItem" name="items" value="Add Item" onclick="addItem()" />
    </form>
    <ol reversed="reversed" class="right" id="myList">
      Unordered list
      <li>item 1:<span id="text">Text</span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. I did not removed reversed cause it was part of the exercise. So it is there cause no matter the items go reversed the item Number should be normal. That was the point of the exercise. Sorry for my bad English but not my mothers language. Thanks a lot for the help. Now everything works perfectly.

Comment: @MarinAtanasov – Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on if you are able to use libraries or not. If you can use jQuery this is a lot easier, if not, it is still doable, just more code. I will write out an answer with both...

jQuery Answer...

```
function addItem() {
  var item = prompt("Please insert a text", "It will be added to the list");
  if (item != null) {
    var count = $('#myList').find('ol').find('li').length;
    if(count > 1) {
        $('#myList').find('ol').find('li').hide();
    }
    var nextItem = count + 1;
    $('#myList').find('ol').append('<li>Item ' + nexItem + ':' + item + '</li>');
  } else {
    $('#text').html('&nbsp;');
  }
}
```

Non jQuery (Vanilla JavaScript)...

```
function addItem() {
  var item = prompt("Please insert a text", "It will be added to the list");
  if (item != null) {
    var n = document.getElementById("myList").getElementsByTagName("li").length;
    if(n > 0) {
        var elements = document.getElementById("myList").getElementsByTagName("li");
        for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            elements[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
            elements[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    var nextItem = n + 1;
    var ol = document.getElementById("myList");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    ol.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML += "item " + nextItem + ':' + item;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "&nbsp";
  }
}
```

There is also a way you can do it to speed it up a little by storing the count as a variable and then increment it each time to get the new number, that way you aren't counting DOM elements each time. It would be a simple addition. Here is an example of that...

```
//inside a <script > tag
var count = 0;
function addItem() {
    var item = prompt("Please insert text here", "It will be added to the list");
    if(item != null) {
        if(count > 0) {
            var items = document.getElementById("myList").getElementsByTagName("li");
            for(var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
                items[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
                items[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
            count += 1;
            var list = document.getElementById("myList");
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = "item " + count + ": " + item;
            list.getElementsByTagName("ol").append(li);
    } else {
        document.getelementById("text").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. There are many...many ways to solve this, these are only a couple. Let me know if this isn't working or you need more help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could also always count how many `li` are in your list and use that for `n`.  For deletion, you just need to hide or remove the item on the first pass.

```js
var ADDED_ITEMS = 0;

function addItem() {
  var placeholder = "It will be added to the list";
  var item = prompt("Please insert a text", placeholder);

  if (item != null) {
    var ol = document.getElementById("myList");

    // Remove the existing LI on the first pass
    if (++ADDED_ITEMS == 1)
      ol.removeChild( ol.querySelector('li') );

    // Get count of LI in list
    var n = ol.querySelectorAll('li').length + 1;
    
    // Create new LI
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    ol.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML += "item " + n + ':' + item;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "&nbsp";
  }
}
```

```css
#nested {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#large {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
ol {
  list-style-type: arabic;
  list-style-position: inside;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="large">
  <div id="nested">
    <form method="get">
      <input type="button" id="resizeBut" name="resize" value="Collapse" onclick="change()" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="button" id="newItem" name="items" value="Add Item" onclick="addItem()" />
    </form>
    <ol reversed="reversed" class="right" id="myList">
      Unordered list
      <li>item 1:<span id="text">Text</span></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```